# Backward selection in R (looping): $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, loops, regression, backwards-compatibility

This is my code:

```
DF <- data.frame(male_data)
Cols <- names(DF)
Cols <- Cols[! Cols %in% "male_data$y"]
n <- length(Cols)
id <- unlist(
lapply(1:6,
function(i)combn(1:6,i,simplify=FALSE)
)
,recursive=FALSE)

Formulas <- sapply(id,function(i)
paste("male_data$y~",paste(Cols[i],collapse="+")))

lapply(Formulas,function(i)
summary,step(Formulas, direction = "backward", trace=FALSE ))
```

Why do I get this error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: This is not an RStudio problem so I've removed the tag and used [r] instead. Please resad tag documentation before use.

Comment: Hi Sya Sya could you please post a sample of the data? This will help to diagnose what's going on.